# Keeping PuTTY/KiTTY from closing the Configuration window when connecting to a new session

Tags: ssh, putty

I tried both PuTTY and KiTTY and both have the same behaviour and I found nothing in the settings, so I'm asking it here.

Every time I connect to a new session the configuration window closes and I have to reopen it to connect to another session, thus I'd want to be able to open multiple sessions at the same time without having to always reopen the configuration window.

Appreciate any help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do not think that PuTTY or KiTTY supports this.

Though there are some alternatives:

- Pin PuTTY to Windows *Start* menu. When you right-click the PuTTY icon in the *Start* menu, a list of recent session opens. Clicking the session, opens the session in a new PuTTY window. But the menu stays opened, so you can open multiple sessions, if you like. You can pin your favourite sessions to the menu, so they stay there.
- Use an alternative PuTTY session manager. There are couple out there. For example *my* WinSCP SFTP client can [serve as PuTTY session manager](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_winscp_as_putty_session_manager). On [WinSCP login dialog](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/ui_login), if you Shift-click on the *"Open in PuTTY"* command, the session is opened in PuTTY, but the Login dialog stays open.

Comment: ah, too bad, but thanks, that was very helpful and solves my issue!